# Bootstrap carousel and css transform scale is not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[Carousel overflow error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4izLq.jpg)

I selected the first item of the above carousel and added `transform: scale(5);` to it but the content is hiding by default. I don't want the overflow hidden. I've tried using `overflow: visible;` but it is still the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**With indicators**

You can also add the indicators to the carousel, alongside the controls, too.

```
.carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active {
    transform: scale(5);
}
```

Comment: The issue is hiding the overflow of the carousel item by default, not indications. I want to stop the overflow from being hidden but the carousel item is hiding by default. I've tried many CSS properties but it is not working on it.